# How to get partition label in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to make a bash script to automate the `dd` command. How can I get the label of a partition without having to slice the output of `blkid`?

Comment: Have you looked at the man page for the blkid program? Particularly, the `-o format` parameter?

Comment: Mind, if you're just trying to find the block device with a given label, there's no reason to use `blkid` at all. Look at `/dev/disk/by-label` -- there'll be a symlink in that directory for every device and partition label, and you can point `dd` right at that link to write to or read from a thus-labeled device.

Comment: ...if you were providing a [mre] showing what you're trying to accomplish, it would be easier to describe how to do that thing without needing `blkid` (or how to get blkid to emit format in a more amenable way, should it genuinely be needed).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that you can make `blkid` output just the raw values and just grep for the label using a keyword.
`blkid -o value /dev/sr0 | grep "keywordhere"`

Comment: After some more tinkering this is how I got it to work without a keyword. `label=$(blkid -o export /dev/sr0 | grep "LABEL") && label=${label:6}`